Shedlock not executing at all with mode PROXY_METHOD
I am trying to lock specific scheduled method using Shedlock.
Shedlock is not running at all, no records are into the database with interceptMode = PROXY_METHOD
While using interceptMode = PROXY_SCHEDULER It's working and locking.
Anyone any idea why is that? I am afraid to use interceptMode = PROXY_SCHEDULER of fear it might break something else.
I am using Shedlock version 4.42.0
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
// InterceptMode.PROXY_SCHEDULER is working while PROXY_METHOD does not execute the locking at all
@EnableSchedulerLock(defaultLockAtMostFor = "PT5M", interceptMode = PROXY_METHOD)
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    FooService fooService;


    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *") // run every minute
    @SchedulerLock(name = "fooSchedulerLock", lockAtLeastFor =  "10m", lockAtMostFor = "15m")
    public void fooScheduledTask() {
        fooService.doStuff();
    }


    @Bean
    public LockProvider lockProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(
                JdbcTemplateLockProvider.Configuration.builder()
                        .withTableName("public.shedlock")
                        .withJdbcTemplate(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource))
                        .usingDbTime()
                        .build()

        );
    }
}


Don't put your @Scheduled methods in an @Configuration class. Move them to a separated class annotated with @Component or something else. @Configuration are processed and proxied differently.

As @M. Deinum said in the comments.
The issue was, because I've used @Scheduled method inside an configuration class.
Moving the @Scheduled method into it's own class and creating bean using @Component have fixed the issue and now Shedlock is working withinterceptMode = PROXY_METHOD
